# Proving a function as an antiderivative

Tags: complex-analysis

Say $f(z)$ is holomorphic on $A=\left\{ z:0<|z|<1\right\} $ and even. I wish to show $f$ as an antiderivative in $A$. I thought if $f$ is holomorphic, we can write:
$$f\left(z\right)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\underbrace{\left(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_{\gamma}\frac{f\left(s\right)}{s^{n+1}}ds\right)}_{a_{n}}\,\,\,z^{n}$$
But $f$ is even, then $a_n = a_n \cdot (-1)^n$, meaning odd $n$'s are $0$. How can I proceed further?

Comment: that's great. The only problematic term is $\frac{a_{-1}}{z}$, but you already know that is $0$. The rest can be integrated term-by-term.

Comment: What do you mean “as an antiderivative?” Do you mean that $f$ “has an anti-derivative,” or that it is an anti-derivative?